# myqsl join performance - joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, performance

I would like to ask for advice if my query can be written differently for maximum performance.

I have 3 tables and need to select some data from all 3.

1. content_type_category c - data from all rows from column c.field_pos_value are needed.
2. node n - need to select only rows where n.nid = c.nid are needed
3. url_alias ua - need to select only rows where ua.src like CONCAT('%/', c.nid)

This is my query:

```
SELECT ua.dst, c.field_pos_value, n.title 
     FROM {content_type_category} c 
        INNER JOIN {node} n ON n.nid = c.nid
        INNER JOIN {url_alias} ua ON ua.src = CONCAT('abc/', c.nid)
```

n.nid and c.nid are indexed. "like" is used because I need to match data written like "abc/nid" (abc/1) (abc/2)...

Comment: Both `n.nid` and `c.nid` are indexed?

Comment: @Schwern please see updated question

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: Does `ua` have `INDEX(src)`?  Does `n` have `PRIMARY KEY(nid)` (or `INDEX`)?

Comment: @RickJames ua.src has index, n.nid has primary key and index

Comment: Then there should not be a performance issue.  Let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Oh, is this for "joining" or for "filtering"?  `ON ua.src = CONCAT(...)`  By "filtering", I mean that there would be a lot more rows if you removed that clause.  By "joining", I mean that it is essentially 1:1, just one has "abc/" and the other doesn't.

Comment: @RickJames I was just looking for best performant query. Tables are very small - maybe 50 rows so the difference would be minimal. Anyhow, I was just curious if it can be written better.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` says what the Optimizer is currently doing; sometimes that helps.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` often has useful info.  Understanding the data (why the 'abc/' thingie) led me up another path.  There are _lots_ of things that factor into performance.

Comment: And, yes, 50 is not a big deal.  But that will grow to a million, then it will be a big deal.  Keep the questions coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All else being equal, `like CONCAT('%/', c.nid)` is the slow part.

Don't do partial string searches in JOINs or WHERE clauses, *unless* it's a start-of-string search and the target field is indexed. End-of-string searches are bound to be slow.

Workaround:

Add a column `nid` to the `url_alias` table, fill it with the part of `src` after the last `/`. A trigger could do this, or you do it in the code that inserts the rows into this table. Add an index to that column. Join against this helper column.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not add columns, "like" is used because I need to match data written like "abc/nid" (abc/1) (abc/2)... So if I can do better match here that would be great

Comment: @user1031742 I can only tell you what's probably slow in this query, and why. If you can't make any changes to the database, you're out of luck in making things any faster.

Comment: Would it be better if I use CONCAT('abc/', c.nid) instead of partial match?. The pattern is always abc/somenumber

Comment: @user1031742 Absolutely. If `abc` is a fixed, known string (or there is a comparatively small number of possible prefixes) then this could improve things.

Comment: @user1031742 Otherwise you could consider using temp tables for this. You can always create temp tables in a database, even as an unprivileged user. If the added overhead of defining, populating and maintaining a temp table is viable in terms of query performance in your use case depends on a number of factors. But it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for filtering or for joining??  `ON ua.src = CONCAT('abc/', c.nid)`

What happens if you turn it around:

```
ON c.nid = MID(ua.src, 5)
WHERE ua.src LIKE 'abc/%'
```

Comment: I guess joining -  I want to select rows that match pattern "abc/c.nid" and extract ua.src from same row. The code returns nothing after suggested change.